# Avoid Evaluation of Function at NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have a huge "black-box" `f` function, which I want to integrate. Let's define it:

```
f[x_,y_,a_]:=a*Exp[-(a*10000)(x^3+y^3)]
```

as a simple toy model. My real function takes many parameters and impossible to write in closed form like a `Exp` function. But the behavior is similar to this toy model function. So, the main idea is `f[x,y,a]` returns a 'number'.

This function has a very sharp peak which I don't know where. Other than this peak, function is zero. Let's pretend that we don't know the peak at `x=0` `y=0` in this toy model. I am trying to integrate it but `NIntegrate` missed the peak with some methods.

```
NIntegrate[f[x,y,2.],{x,-5.,5},{y,-5.,5.},Method->{"GlobalAdaptive","SymbolicProcessing"->False}]
```

So, I am integrating it with `NDSolve`. The simplified code I use is:

```
eqn = {D[u[x,y],x,y] == f[x,y,2.], u[x,-5] == 0, u[-5,y] == 0}
NDSolve[eqn,u,{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}]
```

However, while executing the declaration of function (`eqn` line), Mathematica tries to execute this function symbolically, which takes very long time. Is there a way to avoid handling the function symbolically so that the function at line `eqn` will return just a number whenever it is called?

(Similar to `"SymbolicProcessing->False"` at `NIntegrate`.)

Comment: I tried using `f[x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ,a_?NumericQ]`, but did not work. Still trying to evaluate symbolically. I have also tried with `...D[u[x,y],x,y] == Unevaluated[f[x,y,2.]]` But then NDSolve gave `Encountered non-numerical value for derivative at x == 0`

Comment: I don't think the slowness is caused by symbolic processing, it's probably because the value of `f[x, y, a]` is too large in some area, so the numeric calculation becomes troublesome.

Comment: BTW, the result of `NIntegrate[f[x,y,2.],{x,-5.,5},{y,-5.,5.},Method->{"GlobalAdaptive","SymbolicProcessing"->False}]` is correct, turning off `SymbolicProcessing` doesn't cause any fault here.

Comment: Does `FindMaximum` find the peak?  Perhaps with an increased `WorkingPrecision`?

Comment: @MichaelE2, hmm you mean first finding the peak, then use NIntegrate with defining that point as the exclusion point? I will give it a try.

Comment: I tried, but now a new problem appeared. Since the problem is stiff, `NDSolve` encountered `step size is effectively zero; 
singularity or stiff system suspected` error. When I investigated the function, there is no singularity there. Function is smooth. I think that requires a new thread... God...

Comment: I was thinking that if you can locate a peak at `{x0, y0}`, then you can tell `NDIntegrate` where it is with `NIntegrate[f[x, y, 2.], {x, -5., x0, 5}, {y, -5., x0, 5.}]`.  If there's just a single peak, this will likely solve your problem.

Comment: No one has said it yet, but problems with particular code usually requires the code for folks to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try `ClearAll[f]; f[x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ,a_?NumericQ] :=...`? I don't believe it is evaluating symbolically.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I have just posted my relevant question.