# Evaluation Control for Equation Input to NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, evaluation, hold, inverse

I am trying to numerically integrate a system of equations using NDSolve and am having issues with symbolic matrix inversion taking a long time. The actual system is much more complicated, but I have made a simple example below. Let's assume the system can be written in the form:

```
q''[t] = Inverse[a[q[t],q'[t]].q'[t]
```

where q[t] is a 4x1 vector of variables, and a is a function of the state variables. If we specify q'[0] and q[0] we should be able to solve for q[t]. The problem is `a[q[t],q'[t]]` is a very large symbolic 4x4 matrix so trying to solve the inversion symbolically is very time consuming. Is there a way to force the matrix inversion to hold off (using something like  [Evaluation Control](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EvaluationControl.html)) until the symbolic state variables are substituted with the numerical values by NDSolve? It looks like a related question was asked before [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100727/avoid-evaluation-of-function-at-ndsolve) but without a good response.

Example source code below:

```
n = 3 (* Sets exponent for the "a" matrix, fast if n=1, slow for n >=3*)

q = {{q1[t]}, {q2[t]}, {q3[t]}, {q4[t]}} (* configuration variables*)
dq = D[q, t] (* velocity variables*)
ddq = D[dq, t] (* acceleration variables*)

(* Setting up initial conditions*)
q0 = Thread[Flatten@q == 0.1] /. t -> 0
dq0 = Thread[Flatten@dq == -0.1] /. t -> 0

(* Large matrix that needs to be inverted A = Inverse[a[q,dq]]*)
A[q_, dq_, n_] := Inverse[
{{2*Cos[dq[[1]]], 2*Sin[q[[4]]], q[[3]] + Sin[q[[4]]], Cos[dq[[1]]] + Sin[dq[[4]]]},
 {2*Sin[q[[4]]], 2*q[[1]], Cos[dq[[1]]] + Sin[q[[3]]], Cos[dq[[1]]] + dq[[1]]},
 {q[[3]] + Sin[q[[4]]], Cos[dq[[1]]] + Sin[q[[3]]], q[[4]] + Sin[q[[4]]], Cos[dq[[1]]] + q[[2]]}, 
 {Cos[dq[[1]]] + dq[[4]], Cos[dq[[1]]] + dq[[1]], Cos[dq[[1]]] + q[[2]], dq[[4]] + Tan[dq[[4]]]}}^n]

{tvar, RHS} = Timing[Flatten[A[Flatten@q, Flatten@dq, n].dq]];
Print[tvar] (* print execution time for evaluating A matrix*)

ddqEqs = Thread[Flatten@ddq == RHS]; (* Setting up equations*)
NDSolve[Join[ddqEqs, q0, dq0], Flatten@q, {t, 0, 1}] (* Run numerical integration*)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you vectorize your ODE, and use [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve) instead of [`Inverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inverse). To do so, let's first rewrite your matrix using [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed):

```
m = Quiet @ {
    {2*Cos[dq[[1]]],2*Sin[q[[4]]],q[[3]]+Sin[q[[4]]],Cos[dq[[1]]]+Sin[dq[[4]]]},
    {2*Sin[q[[4]]],2*q[[1]],Cos[dq[[1]]]+Sin[q[[3]]],Cos[dq[[1]]]+dq[[1]]},
    {q[[3]]+Sin[q[[4]]],Cos[dq[[1]]]+Sin[q[[3]]],q[[4]]+Sin[q[[4]]],Cos[dq[[1]]]+q[[2]]},
    {Cos[dq[[1]]]+dq[[4]],Cos[dq[[1]]]+dq[[1]],Cos[dq[[1]]]+q[[2]],dq[[4]]+Tan[dq[[4]]]}
} /. Part->Indexed;
```

Since [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed) is not supported by [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm), I will replace [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed) with [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript) to show it in MathJax:

```
m /. Indexed -> Subscript //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  2 \cos \left(\text{dq}_{\{1\}}\right) & 2 \sin \left(q_{\{4\}}\right) & q_{\{3\}}+\sin
>    \left(q_{\{4\}}\right) & \sin \left(\text{dq}_{\{4\}}\right)+\cos
>    \left(\text{dq}_{\{1\}}\right) \\
>  2 \sin \left(q_{\{4\}}\right) & 2 q_{\{1\}} & \cos \left(\text{dq}_{\{1\}}\right)+\sin
>    \left(q_{\{3\}}\right) & \text{dq}_{\{1\}}+\cos \left(\text{dq}_{\{1\}}\right) \\
>  q_{\{3\}}+\sin \left(q_{\{4\}}\right) & \cos \left(\text{dq}_{\{1\}}\right)+\sin
>    \left(q_{\{3\}}\right) & q_{\{4\}}+\sin \left(q_{\{4\}}\right) & \cos
>    \left(\text{dq}_{\{1\}}\right)+q_{\{2\}} \\
>  \text{dq}_{\{4\}}+\cos \left(\text{dq}_{\{1\}}\right) & \text{dq}_{\{1\}}+\cos
>    \left(\text{dq}_{\{1\}}\right) & \cos \left(\text{dq}_{\{1\}}\right)+q_{\{2\}} &
>    \text{dq}_{\{4\}}+\tan \left(\text{dq}_{\{4\}}\right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Now, we can define the RHS of the equation *(the somewhat convoluted syntax below is to fix scoping issues)*:

```
rhs[q_List, dq_List] = With[{m=m}, Unevaluated @ LinearSolve[m, dq]];
```

Because of the [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List) pattern, `rhs` will only evaluate when fed list arguments:

```
rhs[q, dq]
rhs[N@{1, 2, 3, 4}, N@{4, 3, 2, 1}]
```

> rhs[q, dq]
>
> {-0.906334, -0.657835, 0.728103, 0.99123}

Now, we are ready to use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) (or rather [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) since it is more convenient):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {
    q''[t] == rhs[q[t], q'[t]],
    q[0] == ConstantArray[.1, 4],
    q'[0] == ConstantArray[-.1, 4]
    },
    q,
    {t, 0, 1}
];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. I think this partially solves what I'm trying to do, I'll work through it and report back with what I figure out.